# Can I use a BMW round 20 pin to OBD II adapter with a OBD II scanner?

Tags: obd-ii, bmw

I'm looking to buy an e30 or e36 BMW and 99% of those don't have an OBD II port because they were made prior to 1996 but they all have the BMW round 20 pin I believe. I came across this adapter:[image: BMW round 20 pin to OBD II]and I was wondering if you could then just plug this into a normal OBD II scanner like this one: [Foxwell OBD II scanner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00UJV3E12) and get all the info from it like you would normally. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I don't know for sure because I've never tried it, but would assume if the car doesn't have OBDII in it, an OBDII scanner is not going to work no matter what kind of adapter you have.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar ( or maybe same ) adaptor for my E46 ( 2000, where BMW did not run all the wires to the OBDII port in the passenger compartment ), and it works fine.  Reads all engine and other module codes with my foxwell scanner.  Your mileage may vary.